# What are some USB network devices that will automatically be configured by Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, usb

I bought a USB adapter to connect to wifi and I had trouble configuring it.  What USB adapters can I plug into an Ubuntu computer and expect them to work out of the box?
I want a plug and play solution.  I don't want to have to handcraft config files or find a download site with the right driver.  I want to plug it in, and I want it to work.

P.S.  "Community"  deleted my previous question for vague reasons.  If someone finds this post dubious please explain why. IDK

Comment: Please check here: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Adapters_that_are_supported_with_Linux_in-kernel_drivers.md

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Guys, if you don't submit an answer or upvote my question it gets dumped.  People need to know these things.